# C: How to delete adjacent duplicates in 1D array?

Tags: c, arrays

Say I have an array:

```
int {2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5}
```

and I want to delete all the **adjacent** duplicates so that it becomes

```
int {2, 6, 2, 5}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'delete' whith an integer array.  There are no 'invalid' values to fill in any spaces.

Comment: remove the elements and realloc the memory used

Comment: So. this array, it's been dynamically allocated with malloc() and it has a length var associated with it?

Comment: I mean, obviously a value can be 'removed'. by copying everything above it down one, but that leaves a 'hole' at the end.  You need to explain how that is accounted for, eg. by decrementing some 'arrayLength' variable.

Comment: For instance, removng the dup '2's at the start does not leave {2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5}, it leaves {2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tried. My idea would be like this.

```
int i, num[] = {2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5};

// Prepare new array for the result (result never larger than num[])
int *newNum = malloc(sizeof(num));
int used = 0, last = 0;

// Get number of elements in num[], which is 10 in this example
size_t n = sizeof(num) / sizeof(int);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (num[i] != last)
    {
        newNum[used++] = num[i];
    }
    last = num[i];
}

printf("new array: \n");
for (i = 0; i < used; i++)
{
    printf("%i ", newNum[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not downvote it, but in the first glance,  i can tell you that your answer assume the first consecutive elements is not 0, so {0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5} earns 6 2 5 is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int size = 10;
    int *array = memcpy(malloc(size * sizeof(*array)), (int[]){2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5}, size * sizeof(*array));
    int i, new_size;

    for(i = new_size = 1; i < size; ++i){
        if(array[new_size-1] != array[i])
            array[new_size++] = array[i];
    }
    if(size > new_size){
        size = new_size;
        array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(*array));
    }
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);//2 6 2 5

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```