# A bug about array deduplication

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{


    int n[10]={1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5};
    int m =10;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (n[i]==n[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k< m-1 ; k++)
                {
                    n[k]=n[k+1];
                }
                m--;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",n[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the datas are 1122334455,answer is ok:12345,
but when 1111111111,the answer is 111,not 1.
Please tell me why? thanks!

Comment: because you still increment j even when you delete an element?

Comment: your code is pretty difficult to follow.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this program?

Comment: @fluter  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818325/c-how-to-delete-adjacent-duplicates-in-1d-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove an element, `j` is still incremented, skipping a value. The following prints '1'.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{


    int n[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
    int m = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (n[i] == n[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < m - 1; k++)
                {
                    n[k] = n[k + 1];
                }
                m--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```